# Crash when running a new app where iCloud is on

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud, xcode6

I just wanted to try to code an OS X app using iCloud so I created a new project then set iCloud on:
[image: Capabilities tab]
Because of iCloud's reputation, I ran the app without any modifications just to see if it works but I have this error (after an alert "Build succeeded"):

[image: Xcode's error]

I didn't write any code on this project, so what could possibly be wrong? I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 3 on OS X Mavericks, when I'm running other apps from Xcode it works and when I run the app with iCloud set to off it works too.

Comment: Can you run any other apps from Xcode besides this one? That's a nasty looking error but it doesn't look like it has anything to do with iCloud. It looks more likely to indicate a problem with Xcode or maybe with your Mac.

Comment: When I set iCloud on off and I run the app it works and I can run other apps from Xcode.